# Searching string from the list of files including path containing in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am developing a script which will find particular key or string from the file path containing in text file. I have tried to run below code but I am getting error.

```
import glob

print 'Named explicitly:'
for name in glob.glob('/apps/mongodba/*.conf'):
    with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
         print >> f, name

with open("lst.txt", "w") as f:
    with open('out.txt') as currentFile:
        text = open(currentFile, "r")
        for line in text:
                if "26012" in line:
                    f.write('string found')
                else:
                    f.write('string not found')
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_y.py", line 11, in <module>
    text = open(currentFile, "r")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

**cat out.txt:**

```
>cat out.txt
/apps/mongodba/mongo.conf
/apps/mongodba/mongo_clust.conf
```

**Desired output:**

```
String found on file /apps/mongodba/mongo.conf
```

Comment: The error message you show refers to code that is different from the code that you show.

Comment: Why do you need "text = open(currentFile, "r")" part? Maybe just remove it and change for loop as "for line in currentFile" ?

Comment: This line doesn't make any sense,  text = open(currentFile, "r"). Please review the documentation on open.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @qristjan  after your suggestion i have removed line now the code is working but every time i get single reply string not found although the search string is present in the file

Comment: @malanb5 after your suggestion i have removed line now the code is working but every time i get single reply string not found although the search string is present in the file

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what actually you wanted to do but I see a bug in your code.

```
    text = open(currentFile, "r")
```

The above line is not correct. 
When you `open()` `as` `currentFile`. Here `currentFile` is an object not a string or byte.

Here is a fixed code.

```
with open("lst.txt", "w") as f:
    with open('out.txt') as currentFile:
        text = currentFile.readlines()
        for line in text:
                if "26012" in line:
                    f.write('string found')
                else:
                    f.write('string not found')
```

Edit: If you are not processing too many lines. Then you can do something like this. It is not the best way but a quick solution.

```
things_to_write = []
with open('out.txt', r) as f:
    file_paths = f.readlines()
    for file_path in file_paths:
        with open(file_path.strip('\n') as a:
            text = a.read()
            if "26012" in text:
                string = 'Found' + file_path
            else:
                string = 'Not Found' + file_path
            thing_to_write.append(string)
with open('lst.txt', 'w') as wr:
    wr.writelines(things_to_write)
```

Comment: after making changes i am getting output as >cat lst.txt
string not foundstring not found

Comment: After the line `for line in test:`  add a 'print' statement to debug.  Also add `f.write('\n')` after each write to append a new line

Comment: after print line and print text i am getting output as         /apps/mongodba/mongo.conf

['/apps/mongodba/mongo.conf\n', '/apps/mongodba/ongo_clust.conf\n']
/apps/mongodba/mongo_clust.conf

['/apps/mongodba/rep_fact_reporting.conf\n', '/apps/mongodba/mongo_clust.conf\n']

Comment: Which file has `26012` . `lst.txt`?  I feel the your logic is not correct.

Comment: /apps/mongodba/mongo.conf this file

Comment: still it is not able to grep that error word in that file